# AngularJs directive isolated scope not woking

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angularJs and reading ng-book.

I was trying out the examples related the isolated scope in directives. In the book it has example published in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/OxAlek/1/edit), which uses angular 1.2.0-rc.3 and it works fine. But when I tried the same example with version 1.3.0-beta.13 it doesn't work. I can see the parent value inside the directive with isolated scope. You can see the [code here](http://jsbin.com/yujuk/1/edit)

Can someone guide me on how to get isolated scope working in angular 1.3.0-beta.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set directive's template property to assign it's html or use [transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) if you want to use directive-caller's element inner html bindings.
[See](http://jsbin.com/dagowoca/2/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this a new feature in 1.3.0.XXX, since code is working in version 1.2.0-rc.3?

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't work in 1.2.0:  http://jsbin.com/dagowoca/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Your first one example doesn't actually work at all, `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` in console